# Python: Text saving issue

Tags: python, arrays, string, text, editor

I recently started python, and was coding a text editor in the python console for a project. I have a string array (if I remember it was called that) and each string holds a line of the text (it can vary for the amount of lines, depending on what the user inputs) and I have to save the text to a text document, with the lines spaced out.

*My questions*

I. How do I make one big string that holds all the lines with \n?

II. Once I make the big string, how do I save it to a text file called "tedit.txt"

Info: the string array is called input_list

Thanks!

Code:

```
if cmd == "tedit" or cmd == "td":
    input_list = []
    while True:
        input_str = raw_input("konix@tedit>")
        if input_str == "." and input_list[-1] == "":
        break
        else:
        input_list.append(input_str)

    for line in input_list:
        print line
    save = raw_input("Would you like to save this text to your file? [Y/N]")
    if save == "Y" or save == "y":
        # ???
    elif save != "N" or save != "n":
        print "Not saving"
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Here are a few resources that should help. Please read them carefully, try some things and when you have some more specific questions for assistance then come back and ask them. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings, http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html. The whole Python tutorial is here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join a list of strings with newlines, use the [`join` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
'\n'.join(['first line', 'second line', 'third line'])
```

To write a string to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(some_string)
```

Comment: Thank you, i think I now have an idea of how I would read the file.